# Замена текста путём Unzip/Zip

Tags: c++, qt

Задача - заменить текст в ODT файле. В .net я это делаю просто: распаковываю файл в папку, меняю текст, затем папку пакую обратно в файл. Может в Qt есть для этого специальный класс?

Нашел вот это, но тут упаковка/распаковка файл производится, а нужна упаковка/распаковка папки.

```
void Zip (QString filename , QString zipfilename){

    QFile infile(filename);
    QFile outfile(zipfilename);
    infile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    outfile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    QByteArray uncompressedData = infile.readAll();
    QByteArray compressedData = qCompress(uncompressedData,9);
    outfile.write(compressedData);
    infile.close();
    outfile.close();
}
void Unzip (QString zipfilename , QString filename){
    QFile infile(zipfilename);
    QFile outfile(filename);
    infile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    outfile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    QByteArray uncompressedData = infile.readAll();
    QByteArray compressedData = qUncompress(uncompressedData);
    outfile.write(compressedData);
    infile.close();
    outfile.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Qt есть классы `QZipReader` и `QZipWriter`, правда они приватные и подключать их надо несколько нестандартно.

В общем и целом ваша задача "на минималках" решается так (контроль ошибок, чистку временного каталога думаю добавите сами):

```
#include <QDebug>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDir>
#include <QFileInfo>
#if QT_VERSION == 0x050402
  // Проверяйте версию Qt
  #include <5.4.2/QtGui/private/qzipwriter_p.h>
  #include <5.4.2/QtGui/private/qzipreader_p.h>
#endif

// Для простоты сразу объявим файл, который будем крыжить и временный каталог, куда будем распаковывать
#define MYFILE "/home/arise/file.odt"
#define MYDIR "/home/arise/temp/"

/* Получение списка файлов в архиве
 * QString filename - имя архива
*/
QStringList MainWindow::listZip(QString filename){
    QZipReader zr(filename);
    QList<QZipReader::FileInfo> files;
    files=zr.fileInfoList();
    QStringList res;
    foreach (QZipReader::FileInfo file, files)
        res.append(file.filePath);
    return res;
}

/* Распаковка архива
 * QString filename, - имя архива
 * QString extractTo, - каталог для распаковки
 * QStringList filesToExtract - список файлов для распаковки (если пустой, извлекать все)
*/
void MainWindow::extractZip(QString filename, QString extractTo, QStringList filesToExtract){
    QZipReader zr(filename);
    if(filesToExtract.isEmpty())
        filesToExtract = listZip(filename);
    foreach (QString file, filesToExtract) {
        QByteArray data = zr.fileData(file);
        QFile f(QString("%1/%2").arg(extractTo).arg(file));
        QFileInfo fi(f.fileName());
        QDir dir;
        dir.mkpath(fi.absolutePath());
        f.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
        f.write(data);
        f.close();
    }
}
/* Создание архива
 * QString zipname, - имя архива
 * QString basePath, - Каталог, в котором располагаются файлы для упаковки
 * QStringList filesToZip - список файлов для добавления в архив
*/
void MainWindow::createZip(QString zipname, QString basePath, QStringList filesToZip){

    QZipWriter zw(zipname,QFile::exists(zipname)?QIODevice::Truncate:QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    foreach (QString file, filesToZip) {
        QFile f(QString("%1/%2").arg(basePath).arg(file));
        QFileInfo fi;
        fi.setFile(file);
        f.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
        zw.addDirectory(fi.path());
        zw.addFile(fi.fileName(),&f);
        f.close();
    }
    zw.close();
}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QStringList f = listZip(MYFILE);
    extractZip(MYFILE,MYDIR);
    QFile content(QString("%1/%2").arg(MYDIR).arg("content.xml"));
    content.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    QByteArray data = content.readAll();
    data = data.replace("Договор", "CONTRACT");
    content.close();
    content.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    content.write(data);
    content.close();
    createZip(QString("%1_new.odt").arg(MYFILE),MYDIR,f);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за детальное разъяснение. Не подскажите, как подключить приватные классы? У меня что-то не получается.

Comment: В include если заметили есть версия qt. Можете по аналогии прописать свою версию. или поискать сами заголовочные файлы. к примеру у меня в linux это ~/Qt6/6.2.0/gcc_64/include/QtGui/6.2.0/QtGui/private а в винде C:\Qt\qt5x64\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.4.2\qtbase\include\QtGui\5.4.2\QtGui\private